# Javascript to effect only clicked object

Tags: javascript, html

This Javascript removes or adds the class `selected` to a label on a html form input. If I have more than one group of inputs how do I trigger this Javascript on only the clicked element?

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $$('input').set({
    events: {
      change: function(el) {
        $$('label').removeClass('selected');
        this.getParent('label').addClass('selected');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<input name="state" type="radio" />
<label class="nostate selected">x
<input name="state" type="radio" checked />
</label>
<input name="state" type="radio" />
<br>
<input name="state1" type="radio" />
<label class="nostate selected">x
<input name="state1" type="radio" checked />
</label>
<input name="state1" type="radio" />
```

CSS

```
<style>
.nostate{
    color:grey;
}

label.nostate.selected {
    background-color:white;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Looks like jqueryjquery.

Comment: Not sure it sits in a script tag at the top of the page. It changes the colour of a label.

Comment: What does the variable `$$` refer to?

Comment: This is not standard DOM; you'll need to [edit] your question to include what framework/libraries you're using.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ok, I think I need to do a bit of reading on this. TY

Comment: People only know jQuery these days, but you still should have mentioned that you are using Mootools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?/

```
    <form action="form_action.asp">
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="cream">With cream<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="sugar">With sugar<br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Send order">
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

javascript function as:

```
     function check() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
   }

    function uncheck() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need an ID on each input and a `for` attribute on the labels:

```
<label class="nostate selected" for="input1">x
<input name="state" id="input`" type="radio" checked />
```

Then, in the `change` function, you could get the jQuery element that triggered that event by doing $(this), which would be the `input` tag, and you could then get the label of that input tag by doing

```
change: function(el) {
        var $input = $$(this);
        var id = $input.attr('id');
        $input.removeClass('selected'); // remove the selected class from input
        $$('label[for=#' + id + ']').addClass('selected'); // add the selected class to the label
      }
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for, but can't get it to work on code pen, as it's telling me I have a rogue `(`. Any thoughts as to why this might be: http://codepen.io/denden/pen/dNrWEO

Comment: As a matter of interest, what is the purpose of the backtick after input on `id="input\`"`

Answer (score 0):

So after much cutting pasting, reading and editing this works. Would love to know if there is a simpler way to do it.

```
$(function() {
  $('input:radio').on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    if($('input[name="'+name+'"]:eq(1)')[0].checked){
      $('label[name="'+name+'"]').addClass('arrowup');
    }
    else
    {
      $('label[name="'+name+'"]').removeClass('arrowup');
    }
});
});
```